# Does every framework rely on IoC?

Tags: dependency-injection, frameworks, inversion-of-control, libraries

I've been asking myself for a while about the relation between frameworks and IoC.

Let's have a look to some definitions (taken from this forum):

***IoC*** is a generic term meaning rather than having the application call the methods in a framework, the framework calls implementations provided by the application.

*A **library** is essentially a set of functions that you can call, these days usually organized into classes. Each call does some work and returns control to the client.*

*A **framework** embodies some abstract design, with more behavior built in. In order to use it you need to insert your behavior into various places in the framework either by subclassing or by plugging in your own classes. The framework's code then calls your code at these points.*

*(we can say that "You call a Library, a Framework calls you").*

So, the questions is: does having a framework implies that you have IoC involved? If not, any examples?

Many thanks.

Comment: Look  at Java's [`Collection` framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html). It's an `interface-based` framework that do not rely on `IoC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition for a framework in the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613), you see that the writers think there is a direct relationship between IoC and a framework, or more specifically: To be able to be called a framework, it needs to apply IoC.

So according to that definition every framework relies on IoC.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. And what about The Java's Collection Framework that PM 77-1 mentioned?

Comment: @user2267921: If we follow the definition of the Framework Design Guidelines, the referenced tool is not a framework; it's a library.